# Django No Module Named With Inner Package Using

Tags: python, django

I want to write my own python package inside django's app. It looks like that: I have secondary app. It totally works except one thing. Someday I'd decided to make my app more structured. And there where problems started. First of all, I've added python package(with simple **init**.py inside directory) to the app. Then I've added second package inside that package. And when I try to run django.setup() inside packages' files, I'm getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<primary settings container module name goes here>'`
How to make my custom package's functions working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that settings module isn't "viewable" from your package, e.g. you should add the location of main directory to PATH variable, which could be done like this:

```
from sys import path
from pathlib import Path

path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent))
```

Or you can simply add it permanently to system PATH.